# Can a service that provides a single gettable/settable variable be simplified?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service like this:

```
var app = angular.module('someModule');
app.factory('token', function() {
  var token = null;
  return {
    get: function() {
      return token;
    },
    set: function(tokenIn) {
      token = tokenIn;
    }
  };
});
```

I'd rather have something like this:

```
app.variable('token', null);
```

After 5 years of POJOs, I'm have a small but intense hatred for getter/setters. Is there a better way to do this with angular? provide.constant and provide.value didn't seem to fit the bill. I couldn't find a plugin to do this either-- is there some vocabulary for this concept I am ignorant of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the object directly something like:

```
myApp.factory('token', function(){
    return { Token : '' };
});
```

Then you can inject the `token` factory into your controller and either get or set the token as follows:

```
myApp.controller("Test", function ($scope, token) {
    // set:
    token.Token = 'abc';
    // or get
    var local = token.Token;
});
```

This is about as close to a "POJO" as you can get. Hope that helps!