# Why does angular $http provide a headersGetter instead of just headers?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

When using `$http` the callback functions are called with a headers getter. This often results in the following code:

```
$http.get('example.json').success(function(data, status, headersGetter, config) {
  var headers = headersGetter();
  // Do stuff
});
```

Why is a headersGetter passed to the callback instead of just the headers as an object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a service that provides a single gettable/settable variable be simplified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184829/can-a-service-that-provides-a-single-gettable-settable-variable-be-simplified)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is a headersGetter passed to the callback instead of just the headers as an object?

This is explained in the docs as follows:

> A getter is a function that returns a representation of the model. It's sometimes useful to use this for models that have an internal representation that's different from what the model exposes to the view.

Specific to `headersGetter`, being a function facilitates the following:

> This allows either getting the entire headers object passed in the config, or a specific header value by name (case insensitive).

**References**

- [AngularJS $http API compatibility?](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/84)